# Can't solve for y in a fairly simple work done by magnetic field equation

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, integral-equations

The equations below are essentially calculations for a railgun-type mechanism ([here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-JC_wqgFJV80/UktzcdVr22I/AAAAAAAABaU/XWhFyNZ3Nko/s1600/Railgun+Schema.JPG) is a good image description). I also drew an image using my own variables as definitions:

[image]

I assumed that introducing assumptions would help, to no avail. Here are my assumptions:

$\text{$\$$Assumptions}=\{n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>\, 0},A\in \mathbb{R}_{>\, 0},\{x,y\}\in \mathbb{R},\{\text{x1},\text{x2},\text{y1},\text{y2},\text{lx},\text{ly},\text{rx},\text{ry},\text{y0}\}\in \mathbb{R}_{>\, 0}\};$

`$Assumptions = {n \[Element] PositiveIntegers,     A \[Element] PositiveReals, {x, y} \[Element] 
    Reals, {x1, x2, y1, y2, lx, ly, rx, ry, y0} \[Element] 
    PositiveReals};`

Then I defined a function for the magnetic field:

$B(\text{n$\_$},\text{A$\_$},\text{x$\_$},\text{y$\_$})=\int_{-y}^0 \frac{2 A n x}{10^7 \left(x^2+y^2\right)^{3/2}} \, dy$

`B[n_, A_, x_, y_] =   Integrate[(2*n*A*x)/(10^7*(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), {y, -y, 0}]`

Then force:

$F(\text{n$\_$},\text{A$\_$},\text{x1$\_$},\text{x2$\_$},\text{y$\_$})=\int_{\text{x1}}^{\text{x2}} A n B(n,A,x,y) \, dx$

`F[n_, A_, x1_, x2_, y_] = Integrate[n*A*B[n, A, x, y], {x, x1, x2}]`

Then work:

$W(\text{n$\_$},\text{A$\_$},\text{x1$\_$},\text{x2$\_$},\text{y1$\_$},\text{y2$\_$})=\int_{\text{y1}}^{\text{y2}} F(n,A,\text{x1},\text{x2},y) \, dy$

`W[n_, A_, x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] =   Integrate[F[n, A, x1, x2, y], {y, y1, y2}]`

Finally, a version of the work function that is more comparable to my real-world scenario:

$\text{W2}(\text{n$\_$},\text{A$\_$},\text{y0$\_$},\text{lx$\_$},\text{ly$\_$},\text{ry$\_$})=W(n,A,\text{ry},\text{lx}+\text{ry},\text{y0},\text{ly})$

`W2[n_, A_, y0_, lx_, ly_, ry_] = W[n, A, ry, lx + ry, y0, ly]`

## The Problem

I plugged in some numbers to test out:

- `n = 1` loop
- `A = 1500` amps
- `lx = 0.01` meters (1cm)
- `rx = 0.0005` meters (0.5mm)
- `ry = 0.005` meters (0.5cm)
- `y0 = 0.01` meters (1cm)
- `Ug = (0.1)(9.8)(6.096)` joules (potential energy due to gravity of an 0.1kg (100g) object 20ft (6.096m) in the air)

...and then solving for `ly`, or the length that the rails would have to be in order to make it 20 feet in the air before falling.

`NSolve[Ug == W2[0.01, 0.01, ly, 2.5 10^-3], ly]`

Neither NSolve nor FindRoot appear to be able to make this calculation, and for the life of me I cannot figure out why. What do I do?

Comment: Check `W2[n_, A_, y0_, lx_, ly_, ry_] = W[n, A, ry, lx + ry, y0, ly]`. Arguments are rearranged here.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to W2 in NSolve passes only 4 parameters, your definition of W2 requires 6.  So 
W2[0.01, 0.01, ly, 2.5 10^-3], will return unevaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can calculate all the integrals and define functions explicitly

```
$Assumptions = {n ∈ PositiveIntegers, 
   A ∈ PositiveReals, {x, y} ∈ 
    Reals, {x1, x2, y1, y2, lx, ly, rx, ry, y0} ∈ 
    PositiveReals};
Integrate[1/(x^2 + yi^2)^(3/2), {yi, -y, 0}]

(* ConditionalExpression[y/(x^2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]), 
 x != 0 && y > 0]*)
B[n_, A_, x_, y_] := (2*n*A*x)/(10^7) y/(x^2 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])
In[7]:= n*A*Integrate[B[n, A, x, y], {x, x1, x2}]

Out[7]= ConditionalExpression[(
 A^2 n^2 (ArcSinh[y/x1] - ArcSinh[y/x2]))/5000000, y != 0 && x1 < x2]

In[8]:= F[n_, A_, x1_, x2_, y_] := (
 A^2 n^2 (ArcSinh[y/x1] - ArcSinh[y/x2]))/5000000

Integrate[F[n, A, x1, x2, y], {y, y1, y2}]

(*ConditionalExpression[(1/5000000)
 A^2 n^2 (Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2] - Sqrt[x2^2 + y1^2] - Sqrt[x1^2 + y2^2] + 
    Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2] - y1 ArcSinh[y1/x1] + y1 ArcSinh[y1/x2] + 
    y2 ArcSinh[y2/x1] - y2 ArcSinh[y2/x2]), y1 < y2]*)
W[n_, A_, x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := 
 1/5000000 A^2 n^2 (Sqrt[x1^2 + y1^2] - Sqrt[x2^2 + y1^2] - Sqrt[
    x1^2 + y2^2] + Sqrt[x2^2 + y2^2] - y1 ArcSinh[y1/x1] + 
  y1 ArcSinh[y1/x2] + y2 ArcSinh[y2/x1] - y2 ArcSinh[y2/x2])
```

I guess such a definition

```
W2[n_, A_, ry_, lx_, y0_, ly_] := W[n, A, ry, lx + ry, y0, ly]

n = 1 (*loop*);
A = 1500 (*amps*);
lx = 0.01 (*meters (1cm)*);
rx = 0.0005 (*meters (0.5mm)*);
ry = 0.005 (*meters (0.5cm)*);
y0 = 0.01 (*meters (1cm)*);
Ug = (0.1) (9.8) (6.096) (*joules (potential energy due to gravity of \
an 0.1kg (100g) object 20ft (6.096m) in the air)*);

FindRoot[Ug == W2[n, A, ry, lx + ry, y0, ly], {ly, 5}]
(*{ly -> 9.59142}*)
```